# Cannot convert Float64 to series data for plotting in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, scatter, ijulia-notebook

The following is the code I wrote.
I have no idea why the error happened and how to solve it.
[image]

Comment: please copy your code instead of an image https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your `scatter!` call. The function expects either an X array and a Y array, or `Tuple`s of (x, y) pairs. Here, assuming you want the point (0.2, 0) to be added to the plot, you can just put an extra pair of parantheses around your values:

```
scatter!((0.2, 0))
```

to make it clear that this is an (x, y) pair that you want plotted.